# Dependent Field not populated by itself in IE when running tests through Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I have a Name2 field on my website under test which should populate itself when value in the Name1 field is entered.

The Name2 field is not getting populated by itself in IE on running tests through Selenium RC

On running tests on Firefox the Name2 field is populated fine.

Can you please suggest any way to overcome this issue?

Thanks,
Abhinav

Comment: What is the code you are using to populate the fields.. ?

Comment: From your description, Name2 field should be updated when value is entered in Name1 - it looks like an application issue rather than selenium issue.

Comment: Hi Mike, we were able to solve the issue by using Focus method for the respective fields.

Answer (score 0):

i thinks you are using selenium.type("asasas").

this will not fire any events. it just paste the value in the DOM element using .value or .innerHTML ect..

so the quick approach would be , type native keys

use, selenium.focus("locator");
selenium.keyPressNative("17");

if you want to enter a whole string than a single character, there are many client programmatic approaches

for example to enter a string of numbers 12345

for(char ch : "12345".toCharArray()) {
 selenium.keyPressNative(String.valueOf((int)ch));
}